# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + n - 1$ by iteration

Tags: recurrence-relations

Could anyone show how to solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n-1)+n-1$ with the initial condition $T(1) = 0$ by iteration?  I've written out a couple levels of the recurrence in an attempt to see some sort of useful pattern, but I'm lost on this one.  Here is what I have so far:

$\begin{array}
\ T(1) &= 0 \\
T(2) &=2T(1)+n-1 &=2 \ (0) &+2-1&=2^1-1 \\
T(3) &=2T(2)+n-1 &=2\left(2^1-1\right) &+3-1&=2^2+0 \\
T(4) &=2T(3)+n-1 &=2\left( 2^2+0\right) &+4-1&=2^3+3 \\
T(5) &=2T(4)+n-1 &=2\left( 2^3+3 \right) &+5-1&=2^4 +10\\
T(6) &=2T(5)+n-1 &=2\left( 2^4+10\right) &+6-1&=2^5 +25\\
T(7) &=2T(6)+n-1 &=2\left(2^5+25 \right) &+7-1&=2^6+56 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: First you must find a solution to the homogenous equation $T_n-2T_{n-1}=0$, and then find a particular solution, for which I suggest you to try a polynomial of degree 1.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080437/how-to-solve-vn-2-cdot-vn-1-2-cdot-n/3080533#3080533

Comment: @Fede Poncio I've tried using $An - B$ as a guess for the particular solution, since $f(n) = n - 1$, but this led me to an irreducible equation with 3 unknowns.  Is $An - B$ the correct form for a particular solution in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Multiply each row by an extra power of 2.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
T(n) &= 2T(n - 1) &+ n - 1 \\
2T(n-1) &= 4T(n - 2) &+ 2(n - 2) \\
4T(n-2) &= 8T(n - 3) &+ 4(n - 3) \\
...&...&...\\
2^{n-1}T(1)&=2^nT(0)&+2^{n-1} \cdot 0
\end{array}$$

Now add everything together.

Comment: I apologize, could you provide more details on how this simplifies the problem?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @an0n1234 What is the coefficient of $T(n-1)$ on LHS and RHS? What about $T(n-2)$? $T(n-3)$? Did you add everything up?

Comment: The coefficient of $T(n - 1)$ is 2 for LHS and RHS. For $T(n - 2)$ and $T(n - 3)$ the coefficients are 4 and 8 respectively, both for LHS and RHS.  Adding everything up, I have $T(n) + 2T(n-1) + 4T(n-2) + ... + 2^{n-1}T(1) = 2T(n-1) + n - 1 + 4T(n-2) + 2(n - 2) + 8T(n-3) + 4(n - 3) + ... + 2^nT(0)$

Comment: @an0n1234 Now you can cancel $2T(n-1), 4T(n-2), 8T(n-3),..$