# Finding all of the solutions of the functional equation $P(x+2)+P(x-2) = 8x+6$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

> Let $P(x+2)+P(x-2) = 8x+6$. Find all of the solutions for $P(x)$.

If we put $P(x) = ax + b $ the answer is obvious but how to determine all of the solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get rid of the RHS by using $Q(x):=P(x)-4x-3$ so that $$Q(x+2)+Q(x-2)=P(x+2)-4x-8-3+P(x-2)-4x+8-3=0.$$

Then the solution of

$$Q(x+2)=-Q(x-2)$$ is of the form

$$Q(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x/4\rfloor}Q(x\bmod 4),$$

where $Q(x)$ is absolutely arbitrary in $[0,4)$.

Hence,

$$\color{green}{P(x)=4x+3+(-1)^{\lfloor x/4\rfloor}Q(x\bmod 4)}.$$

Below, an example of a smooth solution:

[image]

and another, piecewise linear and discontinuous:

[image]

Comment: This is my way : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091713/formula-for-the-sequence-0-3-8-15-24/3091719#3091719 OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080437/how-to-solve-vn-2-cdot-vn-1-2-cdot-n

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: sorry but you are pointing at discrete recurrences. The key point in this answer is to find the general solution on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are assuming that $P$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ . Is that right ?

Comment: @S.H.W: right. But the answer remains perfectly valid in $\mathbb Z$ and you can choose $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ arbitrarily, and the rest follows.

Comment: @YvesDaoust And how you get $Q(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x/4\rfloor}Q(x\bmod 4)$ from $Q(x+2)=-Q(x-2)$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: the sign alternates every four units. In other words, the homogeneous solution is "antiperiodic".

Comment: @YvesDaoust My problem is the meaning of "$x\bmod4$" . I know how it's defined for integers but what about real numbers ?

Comment: @S.H.W: same definition. :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust For example what is the value of $\sqrt{2} \bmod 4$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W: $\sqrt2$. What is your definition of the modulo ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $a\equiv b\pmod n  \to  a - b = kn$ for some integer $k$ .

Comment: @S.H.W: doesn't it work with reals ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've got it , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $P(x+2)+P(x-2)$ has degree $n$, hence $n=1.$.

Comment: Thanks but what about other solutions ? I mean when $P$ is not polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

This difference equation is linear so it's solution can be reprasented as

$$
P(x) = P_h(x) + P_p(x)
$$

with

$$
P_h(x+2)+P_h(x-2) = 0\\
P_p(x+2)+P_p(x-2) = 8x+6
$$

for the homogeneous we propose $P_h(x) = \gamma^x$ and after substituting

$$
\gamma^x\left(\gamma^2+\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\right)=0
$$

and the solutions are

$$
\gamma_h = \left\{-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}
$$

so the homogeneous solution is

$$
P_h(x) = C_1\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)+C_2\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)+C_3\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{4}\right)+C_4\cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{4}\right)
$$

now for the particular making $P_p(x) = 4x+3$ we conclude

$$
P(x) = 4x+3+C_1\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)+C_2\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)+C_3\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{4}\right)+C_4\cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{4}\right)
$$

Comment: This is not the most general solution.